# Адаптер с коллекцией для Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Есть класс с полями `id, Name, Image`, описывающий объект `Category`.

Можно ли в качестве списка для `Spinner` установить коллекцию типа

`List<Category> list` и чтобы когда пользователь выберет какой-то пункт получать `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Для этого нужно написать свой класс адаптера (например, на основе `ArrayAdapter`). Пример такого адаптера можно найти [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php).

После выбора соответствующего пункта id можно будет получить примерно следующим образом:

```
((Category)mySpinner.getSelectedItem()).getId();
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую